# Rake - save log from each task to separate file

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm using rake to build my C++ project and I have a lot of dependencies and tasks.

I would like save log from each task to separate log file. Is it possible? I want save all stdout from task to file.

I can't to this like:

```
log = Logger.new
log.info sh "my command"
```

because sometimes I lost info from process because sometimes I run some subprocess, etc. I want all STDOUT but separated for every task.

Can I do this? I tried modify execure function from Task class in rake but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use String Interpolation to Create One Logfile Per Rake::Task

You can use a [Rake::Task#name](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-i-name) to get the name of the current task to interpolate into the name of your logfile. You can also use the task name as the *progname* for your log entry.

A Rakefile can also contain arbitrary Ruby code in addition to standard Rake methods. You can use this to create a custom logging method that allows you to create a log per Rake task, with your shell command's standard output captured using the [Kernel#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) method and passed along to the custom logging method as the log message.

### A Worked Example

#### Rakefile

```
require 'logger'

def log task, msg
  l = Logger.new "#{task}.log"
  l.progname = task
  l.info msg
end

task :foo do |task|
  msg = `echo Hello, world.`
  log task.name, msg
end

task :bar do |task|
  msg = `echo Goodbye, cruel world.`
  log task.name, msg
end

task :default => [:foo, :bar]
```

#### Sample Output

```
$ rake; tail +1 *log
==> bar.log <==
# Logfile created on 2016-03-02 17:31:49 -0500 by logger.rb/53141
I, [2016-03-02T17:31:49.678729 #80846]  INFO -- bar: Goodbye, cruel world.


==> foo.log <==
# Logfile created on 2016-03-02 17:31:49 -0500 by logger.rb/53141
I, [2016-03-02T17:31:49.677165 #80846]  INFO -- foo: Hello, world.
```